# Extract a value from an object in array matching a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need help to make an aggregation pipeline in mongodb.

The mongodb version i'm using is 4.

The documents stored in database looks like this:

```
 [{
    _id : "xxxxxx",
    names : [
        { "lang" : "EN", value : "foo" },
        { "lang" : "IT", value : "bar" },
        { "lang" : "NOLANG", value : "baz" }
    ],
    some : "value"
},{
    _id : "yyyyyy",
    names : [
        { "lang" : "FR", value : "quux" },
        { "lang" : "IT", value : "quuux" },
        { "lang" : "NOLANG", value : "quuuux" }
    ],
    some : "value"
}]
```

I need to add a field with aggregation that contains the value of a certain language (for this example i'll take "EN"), if no element with requested language is found i need to get the "NOLANG" object value.

So, the result of the aggregation must looks like:

```
 [{
    _id : "xxxxxx",
    name : "foo",
    some : "value"
},{
    _id : "yyyyyy",
    name : "quuuux",
    some : "value"
}]
```

This is the pipeline i wrote:

```
[
    {
        $project : {
            names : 0,
            name: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$names',
                    as: 'name',
                    cond: {
                        $switch: {
                            $branches: [
                                {
                                    case : {
                                        $eq : ["$$name.lang", "EN"]
                                    },
                                    then : "$$name.value"
                                } ,{
                                    case : {
                                        $eq : ["$$name.lang", "NOLANG"]
                                    },
                                    then : "$$name.value"
                                }
                            ],
                            default : ''
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

It gives me the error: Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.

What i'm doing wrong? Someone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "some": 1,
    "name": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$names.value",
        {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$ne": [
                { "$indexOfArray": ["$names.lang", "EN"] },
                -1
              ]
            },
            { "$indexOfArray": ["$names.lang", "EN"] },
            { "$indexOfArray": ["$names.lang", "NOLANG"] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2_YYIk-hM6g)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "xxxxxx",
    "name": "baz",
    "some": "value"
  },
  {
    "_id": "yyyyyy",
    "name": "quuuux",
    "some": "value"
  }
]
```